Table 2 Fallacy and choice of variables
I have a couple of thorny questions for you.
I'm conducting an observational study and, after weighting my dataset with weighthem, using g-computation I estimated the average treatment effect (ATE). Below the code that I used:
Formula used:
Treatment_type_tumor_near_gallbladder ~ age_binary + bmi_binary + 
    comorbidities + Segments_treated_per_session_binned + Metastasis_size_at_treatment_mm + 
    min_distance_gallblad_mm + stage_binary + Metastasis_location_superficial

Ratio for the choice of confounders: (1) I chose only those variables clinically significant from all variables in my dataset, (2) I computed the PS using only those variables highly correlated with both outcome and exposure (alpha<0.2 in univariate analysis).

# Perform IPW in each imputed dataset
w.out_model1_ATE <- weightthem(formula, 
data = new_amcore_imputed, 
method = "cbps",  # ebal, cbps, glm, gbm, energy, OptWeight, IPT
estimand =  "ATE",
criterion = "smd.mean", 
) 

After checking for balance both numerically (bal.tab) and graphically (love.plot), I estimated the ATE using the g-computation method:
# PS weighting for the ATE with logistic regression PS
results_all <- with(model_to_use, 
  WeightIt::glm_weightit(log_regression_formula, family = quasibinomial, weightit = model_to_use), cluster = FALSE)

# Compute the ATE on RISK RATIO SCALE
ATE_all <- lapply(results_all$analyses, function(fit) {
    marginaleffects::avg_comparisons(fit, variables = predictors_log_regression,
        comparison = "lnratioavg") # lnratioavg This returns the ATE on the risk ratio scale. To get the ATE on the odds ratio scale, change comparison to "lnoravg". To get the ATE on the risk difference scale, remove comparison and exponentiate.
    })

# Pool the results and summarize
ATE_results <- ATE_all |> mice::pool() |> summary(exponentiate = TRUE, conf.int = TRUE) |> mutate(across(where(is.numeric), \(x) round(x, digits = 3)))

# Print the results
ATE_results

In the code above, I adjusted also for those clinically significant confounders that were not used in the PS estimation because they were not strongly associated with exposure or outcome (alpha>0.2), namely gender, ASA status, and prior chemotherapy treatment (log_regression_formula: complications ~ treatment + gender + ASA + chemotherapy).”
These are the results:



term
contrast
estimate
std.error
statistic
df
p.value
2.5 %
97.5 %




ASA_binary
ln(mean(3) / mean(<=2))
1.609
0.215
2.210
85514.88
0.027
1.055
2.454


Systemic_treatment_prior_local_treatment
ln(mean(Yes) / mean(No))
1.027
0.240
0.113
69958.72
0.910
0.642
1.644


Treatment_type_tumor_near_gallbladder
ln(mean(MWA) / mean(Resection))
0.537
0.233
-2.668
28006.78
0.008
0.340
0.848


sex
ln(mean(Male) / mean(Female))
0.788
0.257
-0.929
49753.64
0.353
0.476
1.303



I have two questions:

Is it appropriate to include clinically significant variables that did not reach the alpha threshold of 0.2 in the univariate analysis when using glm_weightit, or is it better to ignore them?
After reading the blog post at WeightIt documentation (https://ngreifer.github.io/WeightIt/articles/estimating-effects.html#ref-westreichTableFallacyPresenting2013) and the article Westreich et al., 2013 (https://doi.org/10.1093/aje/kws412), I understand that to avoid the Table 2 fallacy, only the treatment’s estimate should be interpreted and reported as an effect. While, for instance, the relative risk (RR) for ASA status should not be interpreted in the same way as the treatment effect. Am I correct in this interpretation?

Thank you in advance.
